# How to parse an XElement string to an array of doubles in C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, kml

```
<coordinates xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"> -12.959611,7.569972 -12.959583,7.574111 -12.875,7.567056 -12.922111,7.593333 -12.872528,7.616222 -12.528778,7.469972 -12.539611,7.424167 -12.527083,7.393333 -12.560861,7.387889 -12.567917,7.44 -12.640833,7.482056 -12.811694,7.538722 -12.959611,7.569972</coordinates>
```

This is my XElement, What would be the best way to get this into a double array?
Right now I'm splitting it on the spaces and then again on the commas but that feels sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

This seems the best to me:

```
double[][] values =
    element.Value.Trim().Split(' ')
        .Select(x =>
            x.Split(',')
                .Select(y => double.Parse(y.Trim()))
                .ToArray())
        .ToArray();
```

I think you're doing the right thing.